# Need a sorted collection of pairs capable of performing floor operation based only on the first member of the pair

Tags: java, collections

I appologize for the title. I don't know what this computational problem is called.

I was hoping there was a collection class ready for me to use to solve this. I use `TreeSet` in the example bellow just to show what I need. I believe the example to be clear enough to explain the question.

```
public class MyClass
{
    //I know TreeSet doesn't work. Is there a collection that would work like TreeSet
    //but has a method similar to the imaginary overload of TreeSet.floor I invoke in my code?
    private TreeSet<OrderElement<Integer, Object>> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();

    //this method is irrelevant to the problem.
    //it's here just for usability of this example class
    public void addElement(int order, Object element)
    {
        treeSet.add(new OrderElement(order, element));
    }

    //this is the method I need to implement
    public Object floor(int order)
    {
        //this overload does not exist. I need a collection with a similar function
        return treeSet.floor(order);
    }
}

//this class represents the elements in the TreeSet.
public class OrderElement<O extends Comparable, E>, implements Comparable<O>
{
    public final O order;
    public final E element;

    public OrderElement(O order, E element)
    {
        this.order = order;
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(O param)
    {
        return this.order.compareTo(param);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return obj.equals(this.order);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.order.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaxZoom that question is not specific to my problem. in fact, it isn't specific at all. it asks for an overall explanation of collections. According the rules, that question shouldn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `TreeMap<Integer, Object>` and your floor method is called floorKey there

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorKey(K)

Comment: Thanks! Now that I see the TreeMap class, I think I should return `treeMap.floorEntry.getValue`